# Android library project class not found error

Tags: android

I have an Android project and want to add a third party library project. The library project has the "Is Library" checked in the properties. I added the library in my main project by going to properties -> Android then added the library. I looked at many stackoverflow posts which suggested this was the correct way to add a library project. I still get a class definition not found error and am not sure why.

Comment: Do you have the code for the third-party library or just its JAR file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the exact steps given in google docs? 
follow it here https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

I quote the required steps here
create a library project based on the support library code:

```
  Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.
    Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:
        Select File > Import.
        Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
        Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding the appcompat project, browse to <sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
        Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.
        In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.
        Right-click the project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
        In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
        Uncheck Android Dependencies.
        Click OK to complete the changes.
```